# Usergrid installation not working after installation

Tags: tomcat, elasticsearch, cassandra, usergrid

I have installed Tomcat 8.0.30 in local Windows 8.1
Cassandra 1.2.18, ElasticSearch latest version (2.1.1)
Followed the exact steps from here
https://usergrid.readthedocs.org/en/two-dot-o-instructions/get_2.0_running_locally.html

ROOT.war is generated and uploaded it to Tomcat.
Tomcat console shows that Usergrid is uploaded.
When I open the below URL in browser, it shows an error 'This webpage cannot be displayed'.
I am not able to proceed with installation any further.

If you need any logs, I can get them.
Can anyone help me about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that Usergrid will work on Windows, but it might.

A couple of ideas:

Usergrid 2.1.1 requires Java JDK 8 so make sure you have that in place.

Check your Tomcat catalina.out log, do you see any "SEVERE" errors around the time that the Usergrid ROOT.war is being deployed. If you share your logs it will be easier to debug this problem.